# classpath error - main class not found or load

Tags: java, classpath

hey guys since i m new to java i don;t to why i m getting such error in my program my code is given below

can u please help me out in setting the environment variable so i can run my program...
i have set the path variable as my jdk path ..do i nedd to also set the classpath as my jdk or where my program is saved...

```
class program {
   String nm = "";
   public static void main(String args[]){
       nm = "myname";
       System.out.println(nm);
   }
}
```

i m getting error "main class not found"...

please help..!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You can't access non static variable inside static method

Comment: Please refer (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please mark your `class` as public

```
public class  program{


}
```

And  as a side note :please follow the [java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).

`program` should be `Program`

Comment: i got my error solved ....the error was in class path variable..naming convention does'nt give such error..

Comment: @user2621278 Yes,That is a side note,Not the actual problem

Comment: @user2621278 You should follow the naming convention, to make your code readable and maintainable.

Comment: @user2621278 you can't access non static variable inside a static block

Comment: Untill unless you change your name to `static String nm` you can't compile your code

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Public class program
  {
         String nm = "";

        public static void main(String args[])
    {
       nm = "myname";
     System.out.println(nm);
 }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fisrt of all change your code

```
 class program {
 static String nm = ""; //this should be static
 public static void main(String args[]){
   nm = "myname";                 //other wise you can't refer it here
   System.out.println(nm);
   }
 }
```

then save this as `program.java`

```
javac program.java
```

then run this

```
 java program
```